# Performance issue with NextJs and GTM

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-tag-manager, lighthouse

Recently I have integrated GTM in my NextJs project. Before the integration was done I used to get 96 on lighthouse performance score. After integration, the score came down to 38.  Is there any efficient way of integrating GTM without hampering the performance of the website?

My integration as follows -  in _document.tsx file:

```
<Head>
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
          <script
            async
            src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}`}
            defer
          />
          <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `
                window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                gtag('js', new Date());
                gtag('config', '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}', {
                  page_path: window.location.pathname,
                });
              `
            }}
          />
        </Head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do this

```
import Script from "next/script";
     
     <Head>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      <Script
        strategy="afterInteractive"
        src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}`}
        defer
      />
      <Script 
        strategy="afterInteractive"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
            gtag('config', '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}', {
              page_path: window.location.pathname,
            });
          `
        }}
      />
    </Head>
```

consider switching "afterInteractive" with "beforeInteractive" and
if that doesn't help you can put the gtag script in footer

Comment: Why footer? And why `beforeInteractive`?
`afterInteractive` should be the goal here since `beforeInteractive` is meant for critical scripts that would for sure increase time to interactive time considering it's nature
Also `defer` is redundant when applied to `Script` since `afterInteractive` is supposed to work the same way

Answer (score 0):

You can also use lazyOnload and nextjs will load the script  after all resources on the page have been fetched.

```
<Script 
    strategy="lazyOnload"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: `
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}', {
          page_path: window.location.pathname,
        });
      `
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me guys

here where i get the solution Dont forget add setTimeout

https://pavelbrecik.cz/the-easiest-cro-you-can-do-is-via-google-tag-manager.html

I added this code to layout.js

```
  <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: `
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'xxxxxxxx');

        // Additional event pushed after GTM initialization
        dataLayer.push({'event': 'afterLoad'});
      }, 1500);
    `
    }}>
    </script>
```